# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'" - How do I stop this?

Tags: python

I am currently coding a book loaning system, with basic language since I am a beginner. So, I have a separate file (see below) with a number representing each book in stock, as well as the stock and target stock number for each book. The user inputs the book and the quantity of it that they'd like to loan. What I would like is for the program to then find out how much stock will be remaining and let them know how many more copies now need to be ordered in order to reach the desired stock level. This is my code:

```
BookNumber=input("Enter the 2 digit number on the back of the book that you'd like to loan\n")
NumberToLoan=input("How many copies of this book would you like to loan?\n")

x = open("BookStockFile.txt", "r+")

found = 0
for line in x.readlines():
    t = line.split(" ")
    if(t[0]==BookNumber):
        found = 1
        CurrentStockOfBook = int(t[1]) #Number of this book in stock
        PreferredStockNumber = str([2]) #Target for the number of copies of this book to be in stock
        NewStockOfBook =(CurrentStockOfBook) - int(NumberToLoan) #Stock of the book after this order
        RestockNumber = PreferredStockNumber - NewStockOfBook #How much they now need to restock after this person loans the book in order to reach the preferred stock number
```

When I run the code, this comes up:

```
RestockNumber= PreferredStockNumber - NewStockOfBook 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I have tried to change the data types of each variable, but the same thing is coming up. Please help!

BTW, my BookStockFile looks like this (first column = 2 digit book number, second column = current stock of the book, third column = target/preferred stock number):

```
12 5 12

16 8 8

13 12 19

19 2 3

18 7 9
```

The spaces separate the book number, current stock level and desired stock level from each other. Thanks in advance

Comment: `PreferredStockNumber = str([2])` should probably be `PreferredStockNumber = int(t[2])`

Answer (score 0):

In this line:
PreferredStockNumber = str([2])

You are casting PreferredStockNumber to a string, then trying to subtract an int NewStockOfBook two lines later. Not only are the types mismatched, but the minus operator doesn't work on strings in general.

I don't think you really want any of your numbers to behave as strings, I would stick with ints for everything.

As mentioned in the comments below, there is also a typo. You have str([2]) instead of str(t[2]).

Comment: And he even has that typo sitting there `str([2])` instead of t[2]. Maybe you want to edit that into your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following code:

```
BookNumber=input("Enter the 2 digit number on the back of the book that you'd like to loan\n")
NumberToLoan=input("How many copies of this book would you like to loan?\n")

x = open("BookStockFile.txt", "r+")

found = 0
for line in x.readlines():
    t = line.split(" ")
    if(int(t[0])==int(BookNumber)):
        found = 1

        CurrentStockOfBook = int(t[1]) #Number of this book in stock
        PreferredStockNumber = int(t[2]) #Target for the number of copies of this book to be in stock
        NewStockOfBook = CurrentStockOfBook - int(NumberToLoan) #Stock of the book after this order
        print "New Stock of Books: " + str(NewStockOfBook)
        RestockNumber = PreferredStockNumber - NewStockOfBook #How much they now need to restock after this person loans the book in order to reach the preferred stock number
        print "New Restock Number: " + str(RestockNumber)
```

As your error was because of the wrong cast of PreferredStockNumber = str([2]) you needed it to cast to int.
Also I assumed you wanted to have the t[2] value.

I would recommend you to split the lines with this character ";" in your .txt File